# how to send message to actor akka

Tags: scala, akka

I'm beginner in Scala and akka, and I want to send message to MessageSender actor if the keybutton was pressed, I draw a field and 2 objects, but when I run a program and then press up arrow, message in actor is not printing

```
//Boot
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.canvas.{Canvas, GraphicsContext}
import scalafx.scene.input.{KeyCode, KeyEvent}

object Boot extends JFXApp {



  val system = ActorSystem("MYsystem")
  val messageSender = system.actorOf(Props[MessageSender],"MessageSender")
  val wiDth = 500
  val heiDth = 500
  stage = new application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Tanks"
    scene = new Scene(wiDth,heiDth) {
        val canvas = new Canvas(wiDth,heiDth)
        var g = canvas.graphicsContext2D
        val tank = new Objects(g)
        val thisTank = tank.drawTank(0,0)
        val thisBullet = tank.drawBullet(60,20)
        canvas.onKeyPressed = (e: KeyEvent) => {
            e.code match {
              case KeyCode.Up => messageSender ! MessageSender.Up

            }}
     content=canvas

    }
    }
  }
```

Message sender

```
object MessageSender {

  case object Left
  case object Right
  case object Up
  case object Down
  case object StartGame
  case object MakeShoot

}

class MessageSender extends Actor with ActorLogging{
import  MessageSender._
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Up => println("sent up")



  }

}
```

Comment: did the below answer work? I'm happy to help with your other scalaFX questions if you provide feedback. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with your `canvas` not getting events. If you move the `onKeyPressed` handler to the `Scene` level it will work.

This is because you are missing the following:

`canvas.setFocusTraversable(true)`

here is a quick example I created:

```
class MsgActor extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case keyCode: KeyCode =>
      println("incoming...\t" + keyCode.getName)
  }
}

object Boot extends JFXApp {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("javafx")
  val msgActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MsgActor()))

  val canvas = new Canvas(500, 500)
  val gc = canvas.graphicsContext2D
  canvas.translateX = 0
  canvas.translateY = 0

  canvas.onKeyPressed = (e: KeyEvent) => e.getCode match {
    case code => msgActor ! code
  }

  // this is needed!
  canvas.setFocusTraversable(true)

  new application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title.value = "Tanks"
    width = 500
    height = 500
    scene = new Scene {
      fill = Color.AliceBlue
      content = canvas
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you very helped me. There is very few information about scalafx, and i will be grateful for any help

Comment: no problem! It would be great if you could mark it as the answer as well.

Comment: Ok, i have rated your answer. And i have a new question about object updating on the canvas. If you don't mind, can you look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669536/how-to-update-objects-on-canvas-scalafx   do you have any idea about it?